# CSS not affecting anything in angular template

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an angular template that has this as its template:

```
<span class="supplement" ng-repeat="s in feeding.stats">{{s.abbreviation}}</span>
```

I have a CSS class:

```
.supplement {
    background-color: rgb(34, 41, 48);
    color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

I can see in Firebug that the span has the right class 'span.supplement', the CSS is correctly loaded in the page.  When I inspect with firebug, the attributes are not showing up.

Why in the world is that?  The directive looks like this:

`<div small-stats person='person'></small-feeding>`

Why is this nor working?  Here's the directive

```
function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: baseURI + "templates/small-feeding-directive.html",
        scope: {
            feeding: '='
        }
    };
}
```

**EDIT**

Stupid mistake, my css link did not have a "rel" attribute and that fixed it.

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem. WHat does *"the attributes are not showing up"* mean exactly?

Comment: `span.supplement`? is that the actual class in DOM?